# MATLAB storing of strings as an array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

> How can I store variable length strings in an array such that I can access them using array index of rows? I want it to be a list or table type structure that makes dynamic input possible.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want. Please post examples, code and anything that could help people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [cell arrays](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). I would preallocate the array if you know the number of iterations:

```
N = 10;
stringCellArr = cell(1,N); // cell array with 1 row and N columns
for i=1:N
    stringCellArr{i} = 'string';
end
```

or if you want to add strings without preallocation:

```
stringCellArr = {}; // empty cell array
for i=1:10
    stringCellArr{end+1} = 'string';
end
```

If you want you can convert that array to a string array, here is an example with a 2D matrix using the [string()](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) function, actually you could also do it for vectors:

```
// This is a cell array ...
A = {'Mercury','Gemini','Apollo';...
     'Skylab','Skylab B','ISS'}

// ... converted to string array ...
strArr = string(A)

// ... and being accessed
str(3,3)

--> will return 'ISS'
```

Comment: How to add entries to it dynamically in a loop? And moreover, how will it respond if num of entries do not allow to make it into a complete square or rectangular matrix?

Comment: @VirataGarwal: I edited my answer to meet your request.